# RadioButton Onclick call a javascript file?

Tags: html, javascript

I am new to all of this as I am trying to learn. If I create a Javascript file(For organization) then have a button, when I click on the button, how can I call the Javascript file in my folders to do what it needs to do?

Button Click ---> Call JavaScript file in folder